# Firebase firestore timestamp query returns no documents

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to retrieve some documents from a collection based on the timestamp falling on a specific day. I know I have documents in my collection that fall between these time stamps but it keeps returning nothing. If I remove the 'startTime' query parameters then I am able to retrieve documents.

Am I querying the timestamps incorrectly?

StartTime stored as timestamp in firestore

```
// Get bookings from firestore
firestore
    .collection('bookings')
    .where('studio.ID', '==', 'kM8p1jSenI4M0Mr1PzBo') /// Works fine with this query 
    .where('startTime', '>=', dayjs(date).valueOf())  /// 1631415616880
    .where('startTime', '<', dayjs(date).add(1, 'day').valueOf()) /// 1631502016880
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {

            console.table(doc.data());
            setBookings(doc.data());
        });
```

[image: Database]

Also tried query as a date object:

```
const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0))); //setting initial state to current day midnight
    const [step, setStep] = useState(0); // Count the days ahead the user is trying to book.
    const [alert, setAlert] = useState(false); // Alert when trying to exceed booking window.
    const [bookings, setBookings] = useState({});

    const bookingWindowAllowed = 7; // Used to limit the forward bookings (evaluated vs state.step)

    useEffect(() => {
        setLoading(true);
        console.log('Set date is:', date);

        const setDate = new Date(dayjs(date).valueOf()); //Date object for today
        const futureDate = new Date(dayjs(date).add(1, 'day').valueOf()); //Date object for tomorrow
        console.log('Set date is:', setDate);
        console.log('Future date is:', futureDate);

        // Get bookings from firestore
        firestore
            .collection('bookings')
            .where('studio.ID', '==', 'kM8p1jSenI4M0Mr1PzBo') /// Works fine with this query
            .where('startTime', '>=', setDate) /// 1631415616880
            .where('startTime', '<', futureDate) /// 1631502016880
            .get()
            .then((querySnapshot) => {
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                    console.table(doc.data());
                    setBookings(doc.data());
                });
                setLoading(false);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log('Error getting documents: ', error);
                setLoading(false);
            });
    }, [date]);
```

Comment: We can't see the data in your database, so we can't tell if that query would actually return anything.  We need to see both the raw data from the query and the database.  Also I'm not sure what you mean by "doc.data() is never undefined".  Are you saying it's *always* defined?  That seems to be what you want.

Comment: I think the "doc.data() is never undefined" got copied from the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query) explaining the `DocumentSnapshot` is never `undefined` in a `QuerySnapshot`.

Comment: Can you confirm that the docs you are trying to fetch have the fields `startTime` in them and that its a number.

Comment: Thanks for taking some time to look into this. I have added a screenshot of the firestore database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `Firestore Timestamp` object instead of using timestamp in `where()` since you are storing it as Timestamp. Also the value is stored in field `startTime` so you don't need `.seconds` in `where()`:

```js
firestore
  .collection('bookings')
  .where('studio.ID', '==', 'kM8p1jSenI4M0Mr1PzBo')
  .where('startTime', '>=', firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromMillis(dayjs(date).valueOf())) 
  .where('startTime', '<', firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromMillis(dayjs(date).add(1, 'day').valueOf())) 
  .get()
```

If you need to use the Unix timestamp in query then you would have to store it as `number` in Firestore.

Comment: Tried this but to no avail. Still the same outcome. I added the full code snippet to the question.

Comment: @Olly can you try `firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromMillis()` instead of `new Date()` ?

Comment: Still no data unfortunately. Logs out a firestore timestamp correctly but no data back.

Comment: @Olly why do you have `.where('startTime.seconds')` ? It should be `.where('startTime')` only.

Comment: Yes! that fixed it, I just notcied that too from when I was just trying all sorts to get it working....

Thank you for the solution!